# Analysis Services slow response after clearing cache

Tags: ssas

My Analysis Services database is responsing really slow after processing. The problem can be reproduced also by clearing cache with the ClearCache XMLA -command. I understand that after clearing the cache, the query performance is slower but I'm seeing slow performance also when using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient library.

I made a small timing test.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
int dc = cube.Dimensions.Count; // cube = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CubeDef
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + start.ToLongTimeString());
Debug.WriteLine("Dimensions count: " + dc.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("End: " + end.ToLongTimeString());
```

For example this will give the following result

```
Start: 8:41:53
Dimensions count: 18
End: 8:43:15
```

So it takes almost 1.5 minutes to get the count for the dimensions. Same performance if I get the measures (which there are only few).

After the first operation all the following operations and queries are fast. My question is that how can I work around this issue? It's a real problem when the database comes almost non-responsive after every database processing. I could do something to automatically "fire up" the database after processing but wouldn't that just move the waiting time from one place to another?

Update:
I've found out the problem. The reason why the performance was different with Management Studio and with AdomdClient was that with AdomdClient I had different connection string to the Analysis Services database. I have some custom stuff at the database which fired with that connectionstring. Anyway, the problem is now solved and wasn't directly related to the actual Analysis Services.

Lesson learned: Make sure you're testing with the correct connectionstring :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question update - the culprit is an incorrect connection string.

Comment: This did not make any difference in my case. After clearing the cache the query you mentioned did run in 1-2 seconds and I experienced the same slow performance in my application as before.

Comment: So, when you run _any_ other query it runs for 1.5min after clearing the cache/processing the cube, but when you run this one it executes in 1s? How about: 

WITH MEMBER measures.X AS
  dimensions.count 
SELECT Measures.X ON 0
FROM [Your Cube]

Comment: After clearing the cache and running that query in Management Studio, it executes in 1-2 seconds BUT when running that query with Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll (AdomdCommand), it executes slowly (roughly 1.5min). So it seems that this issue is somehow only related to AdomdClient?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005 or 2008 and what SPs and CUs have been applied??

Comment: Also, have a look at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlanalysisservices/thread/03fe6bb9-0296-4448-8963-b87489d6d834. It may be worth trying executing the select statement programatically to observe if the problem is with the discovery commands or with all queries in general. Patching the server to the latest possible update could also rectify the problem.

Comment: I've found the problem and solved the issue. I've updated the original post with the update. Thanks for the help Boyan, your ideas helped me to pinpoint the problem.